# SharePoint SendEmail: override Recipient?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a sharepoint workflow I have to maintain. In the workflow a mail is sent using

Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.SendEmail

The "To" - property is set correctly to a valid value (like john@doe.com). But when I look into the ULS log the mail is sent to "test@xx.local" instead.

Nowhere in the code there is any hint that another value might be overwriting the ".To"-property. So I expect this might be a sharepoint-property. Where could I possibly find that?

Comment: Can you provide ULS logs? Maybe it is some sort of SMTP server redirection. You can check currently configured SMTP server in Central Administration -> System Settings -> Configure outgoing e-mail settings.

Comment: Ok. This was weird. It was inside a custom workflow (wsp). So it was inside the code. Two things made this a problem: 1. That code has never been in our repository, so I wasn't able to find that issue. 2. Installing the newest version of the wsp had no affect. SharePoint did not use the new wsp until I removed the feature and tried to install a new workflow. After that I was able to activate the feature again and NOW SP installed the new code.